# How to traverse embedded struct using relfect from pointer to a struct

Tags: go

I have this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type B struct {
    X string
    Y string
}

type D struct {
    B
    Z string
}

func DeepFields(iface interface{}) []reflect.Value {
    fields := make([]reflect.Value, 0)
    ifv := reflect.ValueOf(iface)
    ift := reflect.TypeOf(iface)

    for i := 0; i < ift.NumField(); i++ {
        v := ifv.Field(i)

        switch v.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct:
            fields = append(fields, DeepFields(v.Interface())...)
        default:
            fields = append(fields, v)
        }
    }

    return fields
}

func main() {
    b := B{"this is X", "this is Y"}
    d := D{b, "this is Z"}
    // fmt.Printf("%#v\n", d)
    fmt.Println(DeepFields(d)) //works fine

    // fmt.Println(DeepFields(&d)) //but I need to pass pointer
}
```

Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/1NS29r46Al

I need to do it using a pointer, see the line #44.

Comment: post code here rather posting links to the code.  help us to help you

Comment: The method you are looking for is called `Elem()`.

Comment: @roshan_nazareth I can't place the full code here, could you please see it on play.golang.org, you can run it there.

Comment: @Volker Could you please help me to send the snippet. Though I have tried

Comment: Reflection is always tricky. You must develop a thorough understanding of how you traverse the different types. Elem lets you move from pointer to pointee.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to send both pointer and value elements, you can add this to your `DeepFields` function:

```
if ift.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    ifv = ifv.Elem()
    ift = ift.Elem()
}
```

Modified playground: https://play.golang.org/p/MgB-W81dYr